# Предупреждение "Deprecated Gradle features were used .." при сборке приложения

Tags: android, android-gradle

При сборке приложения появляется такое предупреждение. Что оно означает и нужно ли мне что-то делать?

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Answer (score 1):

Запустите сборку Gradle с аргументом командной строки `--warning-mode=all`, чтобы увидеть, что именно является устаревшими функциями.

Он предоставит вам подробное описание найденных проблем со ссылками на документы Gradle для получения инструкций по исправлению вашей сборки.

Comment: А как запустить сборку gradle? Не приходилось такое делать.

Comment: `./gradlew run --args='****'`